# best practices for download big files using WCF and ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, download

I Have this architecture:

WebSite ASP.NET <------> WCF Service <--------> DataBase

DAtabase gathering very big files.

User request a big file in aspx page, through WCF Service. Service call database, and get the big file.

Now, my entity (datacontract) has those fields:

```
string Data1
string Data2
string Data3
byte[] FileBigger
```

How to send big file throught WCF Service to Website ? which best practices for do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this article from MSDN:

[Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

> When you have a large amount of data
>   to transfer, the streaming transfer
>   mode in WCF is a feasible alternative
>   to the default behavior of buffering
>   and processing messages in memory in
>   their entirety.

[Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx) from MSDN.

> The Stream sample demonstrates the use
>   of streaming transfer mode
>   communication. The service exposes
>   several operations that send and
>   receive streams.

Comment: @alhambraeidos kiquenet did you not notice the 'Sample Code' link in the answer I provided?

Comment: thk, I would like source code of real application or full sample application, but its great

Answer (score 1):

Check [MSDN: Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) out.

Comment: any good sample code source or any sample application ? perhaps in All1Code.codeplex